# Retrieve active locale in Grails application

Tags: java, grails, locale

I know I can use the "lang" parameter to automatically change the current locale as described in the [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/10.%20Internationalization.html), but how do I track those changes, for example to update the language stored in the current user domain object?

`request.locale` does not work, since it does not reflect the changes done via "`?lang=xx`"

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Within your controller you can obtain the locale using the `RequestContextUtils`.

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils as RCU
```

Then to resolve the locale for the request:

```
RCU.getLocale(request)
```

Answer (score 13):

You can also use the `LocaleContextHolder` which doesn't need a request as a parameter

```
import org.springframework.context.i18n.LocaleContextHolder;

LocaleContextHolder.getLocale();
```

Answer (score 12):

Grails uses Spring internally. You can get the current locale from Spring's RequestContextUtils: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/support/RequestContextUtils.html#getLocale(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils

def locale = RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)
```

Check *<g:message>* tag source for more info:

http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/message.html

Answer (score 0):

If you display `properties` of `RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request)` , you will find the following :

```
ISO3Country= 
ISO3Language=ara 
displayCountry= 
class=class java.util.Locale 
default=fr_FR 
language=ar 
variant= 
ISOLanguages=[Ljava.lang.String;@4269f8e3 
availableLocales=[Ljava.util.Locale;@3b532125 
displayName=arabe 
ISOCountries=[Ljava.lang.String;@4ea52290 
displayVariant= 
displayLanguage=arabe 
country=
```