# Locage.getCountry() not returning exact locale

Tags: java, grails

I was trying to get my current locale, I tried it by doing this: Locale.getCountry(), but this one displays US, which is odd since I am in Malaysia! How can I do this? I want to get my exact current locale so as other countries if my little app is access somewhere in the world.

Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will get the default Locale of the Virtual Machine that your program is running in. If that is not set to the correct one, there is little you can do.

Comment: ah, that make sense. But if the app is live, will it display the right locale to where it is accessed?

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7245004/retrieve-active-locale-in-grails-application